# Oracle find tablename given an index name

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the name of an index that is existing on some table on some column in the db(oracle 11g). Knowing the name of the index, how can i find which table it belongs to?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
SELECT table_name
FROM all_indexes
WHERE index_name = 'YOUR_INDEX'
```